# Objective C - deallocated variable

Tags: objective-c

I have this static/singelton class that has a member variable.

Everything works just fine, however, when I quit the app, and the come back, that member variable is causing the app to crash.

I tried reinitializing the member variable, but doesn't seem to do the trick.

I am including samples of my code below, has anyone seen this before?

The header (.h) file:

```
@interface Metrics : NSObject {
Metrics *metrics;
Distance *distance;
}
```

The implementation (.m) file:

```
@implementation Metrics

static Metrics *metrics = nil;

+ (Metrics *)sharedInstance {
@synchronized(self) {
    if (metrics == nil) {
        metrics = [[Metrics alloc] init];
    }   
}

return metrics;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

    }

    return self;
}

-(void) setupDistance
{
    distance = [[Distance alloc] init];
    distance.test; // it dies here after I quit the app and come back
}
```

And where it is used, AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[Metrics sharedInstance] setupDistance];
}
```

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: What does the crash say (i.e. what do you see in the console when it crashes, and what does the call stack look like)?

Comment: Is this an iOS app? Also, please post the declaration of Distance and the implementation of `getTest`;

Comment: @Perception: what getTest? ISTM he is invoking the method test as a property.

Comment: (1) what does "dies here" mean? If it crashes, post the crash.   (2) Objective-C does not have member variables.  It has instance variables.

Comment: What is `distance.test`?  If it's a proprty or method, post the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "quit the app" you almost certainly mean "send the app to the background." This does not terminate your application. When you become active again, you're leaking `distance` and assigning a new one. I suspect that something in `test` is actually the problem.

First, don't access your ivars directly, except in `init` and `dealloc`. Use accessors. This will make most of your problems go away.

Second, don't call `setupDistance` in `applicationDidBecomeActive`. You mean to call it in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. But better yet, just initialize it during `Metrics init`. Why have this internal `Metrics` detail in the app delegate?

Answer (score 1):

applicationDidBecomeActive will get called when it comes back from sleep calling to setup in the distance again.  It's wierd that you're calling a property (.test) and not assigning.  Is test doing work?  Should it be a method?  What's it doing?

Also, in a singleton you have to overload quite a few things.  Here's a good template for a singleton that I use.

```
 static MySingleton *sharedInstance = nil;

 @implementation MySingleton

 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark class instance methods

 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark Singleton methods

+ (MySingleton*)sharedInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (sharedInstance == nil)
            sharedInstance = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];

        return sharedInstance;  // assignment and return on first allocation

        }
    }

    return nil; // on subsequent allocation attempts return nil
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return self;
}

- (id)retain {
    return self;
}

- (unsigned)retainCount {
    return UINT_MAX;  // denotes an object that cannot be released
}

- (void)release {
    //do nothing
}

- (id)autorelease {
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Meh;  you don't have to overload any of that to make a singleton.  I've never bothered and it works fine;  overriding retain/release/autorelease, etc, is just being defensive against buggy code that should be fixed.

Comment: Agree with bbum.  I've always used the pattern in the question.  It's much better to design your class so that it can be used in a non singleton context than to stop people from instantiating it in a non singleton context IMHO.

Comment: I think you need to decide if it's a singleton, an instance class or both.  If it's a singleton, then make it one and avoid hard to find bugs - you can also add log error (or debug assert) statements in release etc... if you want to find folks that are calling it inappropriately.  If you don't override, you don't have the opportunity to find code that's inappropriately using the class (as a non-singleton) which can lead to even harder to find bugs.

Comment: I understand the sentiment, but in 20+ years of writing Obj-c and fixing other people's code, I've never run into the need for all that extra gunk.  A DEBUG NSLog or @throw-past-first-call in retain, might be useful in the pure singleton case.  The "recommended" uber-defensive code just hides misuse, making it harder to refactor into non-singleton roles later (which seems inevitable).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and thoughts - I'm only a year or two into obj-c but 15+ of other C stuff so perhaps my instincts around good asserts finding bugs is kicking in :)  I also hate hiding mis-use - make it clear how to use.  I've always been a fan of debug asserting to expose potential bugs that are much harder to find later.  If the case should never happen - assert it won't and expose it.  But, I also agree with the sentiment of gunking up the code - I've seen code that was too defensive and you couldn't see the logic.  Definately a balance ... Thanks